# How to require Google maps Geocoding script on Worklight

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, dojo, ibm-mobilefirst

I copy, after setted api key( Should I generate a special key(browser,adnroid)?? ) , a html code of [this page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple) (Google Maps JavaScript API v3) in a new html page, and all works perfectlly.

This is a script of html page that works:

```
 <script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCo1Q9VJ...xr7R4aOBDzY&sensor=false">
    </script>
```

On Worklight Prject, with Dojo, the maps isn't show.

I import the script with [dojo/request/script](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/request/script.html) . This is .js code:

```
     function dojoInit() {
            require([ "dojo",  "dojo/request/script","dojo/parser",

                   ..

                  ], function(dojo,script) {
    dojo.ready(script,function() {


                script.get({
                    url : "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js",
                    content : {
                        libraries : "places, geocode",
                        sensor : "false",
                        callback : "initialize",
                        key: "AIzaSyCo1Q9....cqXhAxr7R4aOBDzY"
                    }
                 });
    ...
            });
        });

    }
```

The initialize() function:

```
function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
    var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 8,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
}
```

build-dojo.xml

```
..
<include name="dojo/request/script.js" />
```

The view is empty and not display the map.

There are no errors on browser's console but the function initialize isn't call.Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by importing the script in html

```
    <script type="text/javascript"
          src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaS..OBDzY&sensor=false">
        </script> 
<div dojoType="dojox.mobile.ContentPane"  style="overflow:auto;">

        <div id="map_canvas" style="height:1000px"></div><!--  cambiare style  -->

    </div>
```

and calling the function initialize() in dojo_init(). The map is displayed as well [image]
I think it's a CSS problem

Answer (score 2):

Use dojo io load to make sure the google api is loaded before running the rest of your code.

```
dojo.io.script.get({
            url : "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js",
            content : {
                libraries : "places, geocode",
                sensor : "false",
                callback : "initialize",
                key: "AIzaSyCo1Q9VJDuH96CqqW8cqXhAxr7R4aOBDzY"

            }
```

Comment: where i place this code?Because I insert it after dojo init function and the this error :"TypeError: dojo.io is undefined" show   It's deprecated http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/io/script.html

Comment: dojo.io.script.get is deprecated . I use this http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/request/script.html#dojo-request-script    but don't work !

Comment: Error when it import "dojo/request/script", but i see that this file exists

Comment: You will have to add it to the dojo build.  find build-dojo.properties  .  Find the patternset tag.  Add <include name="dojo/request/**"/>

Comment: TypeError: script.get is not a function .

Answer (score 1):

also you need your require callback function to correctly map your require array arguments. Here it looks like you import several modules but you do only have 2 arguments to your require callback.

if you do

```
require(["a", "b", "c", "dojo/require/script"], ...)
```

the function should be

`function(a, b, c, script)` and not just `function(a, script)`

if you don't care about b & c you might do:

```
require(["a", "dojo/require/script", "b", "c"], function(a, script){});
```

Comment: thanks, the script "works", but i don't understand why the function initialize isn't call.